# get specific properties within the generic list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I have generic list foo as shown below

```
var foo = new List<XYZ>();
public class XYZ
{
    public String TimeZone { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B1Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B2Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B3Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B4Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B5Volume { get; set; }
    // .............
    // .............
    public Decimal? B24Volume { get; set; }
    public String Name {get;set;}
}
```

how do I select the properties `B1Volume,........B24Volume ?`

I tried with following code mentioned below, but it's not giving expected results

```
var hp = foo.Skip(1).Take(23).ToList();
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't help. `Skip` , `Take` ... works on objects not their properties. It works when you have a list like this: `{xyz1, xyz2 .... xyz24}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps:

```
XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
Type t = xyz.GetType();
List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>(t.GetProperties());
var hp = properties.Skip(1).Take(23).ToList();
```

Do not forget adding name space:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

**Update**

In comments GBreen12 suggests to add a filter for getting only properties that has name containing `volume`. Now if you add another properties the code will not fail. So you can change the 3th line to this:

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = (new List<PropertyInfo>(t.GetProperties())).Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Volume")).ToList();
```

Now you do not need last line `var hp = ...` and the `properties` is your answer.

Comment: I would suggest not assuming the return from `GetProperties` is the same order as the declaration (though that is the case with the current compiler) and filter on the property names.

Comment: @NetMage I tested the exact class `XYZ` and properties are in same order.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi I think what NetMage is trying to say is that it's not really safe to assume the order of the properties for various reasons. Even if right now they return in the right order, the object definition could change in any number of ways that would screw that up.

Comment: @GBreen12  Thanks. What you mean *object definition could change in any number of ways*?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi An example would be if the developer added a Property above all the `BnVolume` properties, then the linq query would return that new property and leave off the `B24Volume` property.

Comment: I feel like if you're going to do it this way, you should do some sort of `Where` like `.Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Volume"))`. In which case you wouldn't need the `Skip` or `Take`

Comment: Ok. I think if the developer changes the properties, so must change the code...  But I will add your suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Except you are assuming the compiler also won't change the order of the properties, but I could see some types of optimization added to future versions changing the property order without any code changes and breaking the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways, but I do not think that you want to go down that road.
Do you really want a list of xyz? Or asked in a different fashion: Do you have many different lists of lists of volumes? Or do you only want to express a single list of volumes?

Maybe what you want to do is declare an array inside XYZ like this

```
public class XYZ
{
    public String TimeZone { get; set; }
    public Decimal?[] Volumes {get; set;} = new Decimal?[24];
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

If you want to access volumes by an index (1,2,...,24) you need an array or any other kind of indexed data structure.

Then you could do

```
var xyz = new XYZ();
xyz.Volumes[0] = 12.0;
xyz.Volumes[1] = 23.0;
.....
```

and basically access the volumes by xyz.Volumes and adding an index to get the n-th volume

If you now want to further list these XYZ you could do something like this:

```
var listOfXyz = new List<XYZ>();
listOfXyz.Add(new XYZ());
....
listOfXyz[3].Volumes
```

this would give you the 24 volumes of the element at the index of 3 in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `Select`:

```
var hp = foo.Select(x => new { x.BVolume1, x.BVolume2, ..., x.BVolume24 });
```

Although I do agree with @Himzo that this is not the best way to solve your problem if you can change the structure.